# F# Type Initialization Exception with Async Parallel iteration

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, f#, type-providers, typeinitializeexception

I am getting the error "Type Initialization Exception occurred in File.exe; the type initializer for File.Mod2 threw an exception." However the breakpoint on the exception is in Mod1--where incidentally there is nothing declared, nothing in the Locals window, nothing to debug... .

I thought it might have to do with whether I declare the type SqlDataConnection in one module or separately in each, or whether I assign db.GetDataContext globally in one module, in each module, in each function it's needed, or in one function and then pass it up/ around. But moving declarations around is not helping. (I got this error rarely in the past, and it kind of fixed itself. I forget, it was so rare, either I would hit continue. Or I would start over and not touch SQL Server while running.)

This code worked for weeks, able to run days at a time and upload 500M+ results. I'm always revising, but I don't think I touched anything in the Type Provider or database parts.

One final point: I can pinpoint exactly where in the iterations the exception is thrown after some detective work. As mentioned, the debugger breaks with the exception on the one line in Mod1. But if I walk through the iterations, the break follows upon the completion of the first ID in "IDList |> List.iter (fun ID -> GetDataLists ID |> IterateParams ID paramLists )", in Mod2. The break occurs after the last UpLoad result in Mod4, when the code should return to Mod2 for the next ID, but instead breaks in Mod1, at the first, most abstracted call. Finally, note that the error message says the exception was thrown in Mod2--even though the break is in Mod1. (And I can't step from Mod4 to Mod2 to examine the exception conditions--it jumps from Mod4 to Mod1.)

EDIT*** I got one detail wrong. The break does not jump from Mod4 to Mod1. Mod4 does return to Mod2. Flow returns to AsyncSeries in Mod2, from the last upload in Mod4 (which succeeds), if I step carefully. Then the next step from AsyncSeries in Mod2 is to the one line in Mod1.

Here is abstracted code just to try to illustrate the flow, with notes on the exception.

```
namespace MyNameSpace

module Mod4 =  //type provider is used here
    let UpLoadOneResult ID result = ... //****Last result of 1st ID uploads. 
                    //Exception then in Mod1--instead of iterating in Mod2. 
    let UploadResults ID resultsList = 
        resultsList |> List.iter (fun r -> UploadOneResult ID r)


module Mod3 = //type provider is used here
    let rec SolveResults ID kList mList rev resultList (x, y, z, w) = ...
        SolveResults ID kList.Tail mList.Tail newResultList (x, y, z, w)        


module Mod2 =
        type dbSchema1 = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.
        SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=DESKTOP-55M3AJ5\SQLEXPRESS;
        Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True;
        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;">   
        //I omit this from example modules above, but they do have 
        //dbSchema2, etc. 

    let GetParamLists = ...  //this func just hard coded. my user interface for now.
        (xList, yList, zList, wList)

    let GetDataLists ID = 
        let db1 = dbSchema1.GetDataContext()    // "use"? "new"? () as argument? 
        let kList = query { for row in db1.Data ... } |> Seq.toList 
        let mList = query { for row in db1.Data ... } |> Seq.toList 
        (kList, mList)

    let IterateParams ID (xList, yList, zList, wList) (kList, mList) =   

        let MakeParamCombos xList yList zList wList =
            [for x in xList do
             for y in yList do 
             for z in zList do
             for w in wList do
             yield (x, y, z, w)]

        let AsyncSeries (x, y, z, w) = async { 
            return  SolveResults ID kList mList [] (x, y, z, w)        
            |> UpLdResults ID   }

        MakeParamCombos xList yList zList wList
        |> List.map AsyncSeries
        |> Async.Parallel 
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> ignore


    let CalcResults  =   
        let db1 = dbSchema1.GetDataContext()
        let paramLists = GetParamLists
        let IDList = query { for row in db1.Data ... } |> Seq.toList
        IDList |> List.iter (fun ID -> GetDataLists ID |> IterateParams ID paramLists ) 
        //*** the first ID run completes. Code fails to return here for 2nd ID. 
        ()


module Mod1 =
    [<EntryPoint>] 
    let main argv =
        CalcResults |> ignore    //**ERROR point, on second iteration of "IDList |> List.iter ... "
        0
```

Comment: In Mod2, at the fateful "IDList |> List.iter", IDlist is given as type int list, and the argument of GetDataLists is type int. And when I break here on the first pass, IDList looks okay in Locals window.

Comment: Big "hmmmm" here: if I comment out the query that defines IDList and hard code a list of IDs: 1. it works fine on a list of like [4; 6; 10; 12]. But it breaks on [1; 2; 3; 4]. And ID 1 is also the first in the query, causing the break. So I guess it's something squirrelly in the data, probably. But with the nature of this exception jumping to the wrong module and nothing in Locals--this is like 1980s era debugging, or worse, now.

Comment: But if there were any best practices to follow with regard to where to declare the SQL Data Connection type and the GetDataContext assignment--that might help and would be much appreciated in any case.

Comment: Just for more info: the last line for ID 1, after which the exception occurs is "db3.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(@"INSERT INTO Data.dbo. ... ", in Mod4. Let me confirm whether this line actually succeeds or fails. it is in a "try" block, "with | exn -> ()".

Comment: Now that I see the return to Mod2 which I missed sloppily, maybe I can get something out of Locals there.

Comment: Have you noticed that `CalcResults` is a value, not a function? So it's getting evaluated _before_ `main` is executed.

Comment: What is `InnerException`?

Comment: Thanks for commenting Fyodor. I'm not sure what you mean by InnerException, but the fundamental and simple error I have with the empty list is not represented in my abstracted code above. The error occurs in part of IterateParams that I elided (I couldn't put 10 pages of code due to length and being proprietary to work). The upshot of the whole situation for me is that for whatever reason (Async?) my empty list turned into a Type Initialization error, in the wrong module, with no debugging context (with code stepping almost impossible).

Comment: Also I'm glad you mentioned that CalcResults is a value. I noticed the same point in another post where someone else was trying to have db.GetDataContext(). In that post, it was suggested to turn the assignment from value to a function by adding () as an argument. I don't know the impact of that difference. For my calls, I don't know whether or why I would have either 1. let or do, 2. () or no argument, 3. new or not have new. When I tried to replicate some of the code in the other post, I got errors. So syntax may have changed with versions. But I don't appreciate these distinctions here.

Comment: `TypeLoadException` has a property `InnerException`, which will tell you the actual error.

Comment: And I know I mixed up your point. You pointed out function vs value vis a vis CalcResults. I switched to raising that question re GetDataContext. I don't have a great sense of how to distinguish those forms of calls and their various significances in either case.

Comment: I don't see how to access that Property. Sorry if I'm ignorant of something simple (I've have to do a lot more VBA than .Net...). The pop up window doesn't have that term. It has 4 links: "Get general help for this exception." "Search for more Help Online." "Copy exception detail to clipboard." "Open exception settings." Here's what goes to clipboard:
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in File.exe
Additional information: The type initializer for 'File.Mod2' threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is simply that in one of my new edits I don't check for an empty list before taking List.Head in a place where I get an empty list with ID 2 (after ID 1...). So this question was a bit of a wild goose chase. The error was trivial. But it's not (just) that I'm entirely an idiot: In my processes for whatever reason, this elementary error caused an inscrutable exception and exception environment. And: it's not just that it never occurred to me to step through the code. Rather, the error would jump ahead of me when trying to step through--unless I put a break point on every single line in the code, and then stepped through it with F11.

I should probably delete this whole mess. I'll wait a few hours and look for a sign re that.

Comment: Well I'm able to run overnight without an error again. Kind of, or barely. That is, my code ran without errors--but some time during the night MSFT decided that updating Win 10 was more important than running sims--for my g/d job. So they rebooted me a small fraction of the way in. Great. Thanks.